# When running sql query with mysql_query() I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been struggling with a search function and now when I want to rewrite my table i have to get all my data from my database again.

But now when i use this code I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in ..

My code:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT `statusref`.`status_ID`, `tblapparaten`.*, `status`.`status`  FROM `tblapparaten` 
            LEFT JOIN `opvolging`.`statusref` ON `tblapparaten`.`apparaat_id` = `statusref`.`apparaat_ID`
            LEFT JOIN `opvolging`.`status` ON `statusref`.`status_ID` = `status`.`status_ID`
            WHERE (`apparaat` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
            OR (`serienummer` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
            OR (`klacht` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
            ORDER BY $field $sort ");
```

Comment: Thanks for editing, i'm new to this site and have no idea how to post code decently.

Comment: Firstly, mysql is deprecated and should no longer be used, switch to mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: What are the values of `$query`, `$field` and `$sort` ?

Comment: @BertvanDijck Then I think these 2 links will help you much: http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I have a project going and this is like my first time i do things like this for my last year on school. We have learned it with mysql and i know its outdated but i'm afraid to switch to mysqli for messing up the whole project.

Comment: $query contains the string which i gave in an input for the search function. $field and $sort are used for sorting my table.

Comment: @BertvanDijck Show us the values with `var_dump($query);` ... -> output?! [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30071296/edit) your question!

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea how this all works ..

Comment: i have a table with information and when i type into the search bar "BOSCH" and press the submit button then $query will be "BOSCH"

Comment: @BertvanDijck 1. Add the following lines in your code right before you run your sql query: `var_dump($query); var_dump($sort); var_dump($field);` 2. Take the output of all 3 which will be something like: `string(2) "xy"` and edit your question 3. Use the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30071296/edit) button! (4. Format it nicely! How? -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @BertvanDijck Also add on which line the error occurs and mark it with a comment in the question

Comment: `T_LOGICAL_OR` is the literal operator `or`. Are you sure the error is in the code you have given? Which line does it point to exactly? I can only assume a missing quote somewhere is causing the `OR` to be read as PHP and not part of the MySQL string...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Or it's one line above the code which we see :)

Comment: Can you show us the statement after processing? (I.e. without ".$query. etc.)

Comment: Guys i appreciate the help^but i've got my way out on another way :D i just copied to much code to another... the ORDER BY part was to much here i didnt need it